# In JUnit, will @After method run, when @Test method throws an exception which is unhandled?

Tags: java, junit, unhandled-exception

How will I make sure that my @After method runs even if @Test method throws an exception which is unhandled or this is actually internally done by JUnit?

Comment: *... or this is actually internally done by JUnit?* Try it out and you will know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JUnit runs methods annotated with `@After` after each test case regardless of thrown exceptions.

To quote [the JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/After.html):

> All @After methods are guaranteed to run even if a Before or Test method throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an `@After` method is always run, even if an exception is thrown in a `@Test` method.

The test will fail if it isn't configured with `@Test(expected=ExceptionClass.class)`.